# How do I change the lights in a traffic light on a timer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, timer

I have made a set of traffic lights that light in sequence but I want to load a timer when the web page is opened that changes the lights in sequence every 2 seconds, instead of clicking a button.

I attempted to do this but it's not working, if any of you know why and can help, please do. Thanks.

```
<html>

<body onload="timer()">

    <div class="container">
        <button class="btn" onclick="traffic_lights()">Change Lights</button>
        <img id="traffic-light" src="" alt="traffic lights">
    </div>

</body>

<script>

    var traffic_light_img = [];

    var i = 0;

    function traffic_lights() {
        if (i <= 3) {
            i++;
            document.getElementById("traffic-light").src = traffic_light_img[i];
        } else {
            i = 0;
            document.getElementById("traffic-light").src = traffic_light_img[i];
        }
    }

    function timer() {
        setInterval(traffic_lights, 2000);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You code **already** affects the traffic lights automatically based on a timer. The only problem is that you don't include any images to load, and that you increment your index before loading the images. Remember, lists start at index 0!

Instead of:

```
if (i <= 3) {
  i++;
  document.getElementById("traffic-light").src = traffic_light_img[i];
}
```

You need:

```
if (i < 3) {
  document.getElementById("traffic-light").src = traffic_light_img[i];
  i++;
}
```

Here's the full code, complete with some placeholder images:

```html
<html>

  <body onload="timer()">

    <div class="container">
      <img id="traffic-light" src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="traffic lights">
    </div>

  </body>

  <script>
    var traffic_light_img = [
      "http://placehold.it/200",
      "http://placehold.it/300",
      "http://placehold.it/100",
    ];

    var i = 0;

    function traffic_lights() {
      if (i < 3) {
        document.getElementById("traffic-light").src = traffic_light_img[i];
        i++;
      } else {
        i = 0;
        document.getElementById("traffic-light").src = traffic_light_img[i];
      }
    }

    function timer() {
      setInterval(traffic_lights, 2000);
    }

  </script>
```

I've also removed the button in the above sample, as it's not needed.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I have the images loaded in my actual code but the site doesn't allow links in code so I had to remove them.

Comment: you could remove the conditionals if you used i = (++i)%3;

Comment: @Pete -- True, and good catch :) Though this is a standard JavaScript assignment problem, and it might cause suspicion if he used modulo ;)

Comment: Thanks for this though :)

Comment: No problem :) If this answer solved the problem for you, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)